# New a scala class with another class as param meet "type mismatch" error?

Tags: class, scala

```
class base[T] () {
    def tell(t: T) { }
}

class test[T](a: T, b: base[T]){
    b.tell("sssssssssss")
}

val b = new base[String]()
val s:String = "12354555"
val t = new test[String](s, b)
```

I have two classes, one is class **base**, the other is **test**.
Class **test** has two params.

After run the code, I get such a **type mismatch** error.

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("sssssssssss")
 required: T
    b.tell("sssssssssss")
               ^
one error found
```

In my code, already defined a type **String** b, but in class **test** the type of b is **T**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At compilation moment type variable **T** in class **test** is not **String**, but you try to call it with **String**

Two possible solutions:

a) Set Lower bounds for paramter **T**

```
class test[T >: String](a: T, b: base[T]){
    b.tell("sssssssssss")
}
```

b) Or change type of prameter **b**:

```
class test[T](a: T, b: base[String]){
    b.tell("sssssssssss")
}
```

Comment: thx. it's really works. My code is abstracted from twitter's **Scala School** concurrency chapter[link](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html). At the end of the chapter, there is a Producer/Consumer demo. A class 'class Producer[T](path: String, queue: BlockingQueue[T])'. 'val queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue[String]()', 'queue' is a instance of 'BlokingQueue[T]' , then pass the **String** type 'queue' as param to   Producer. I run the code. 'queue.put(line)' calls a **type miss match error**. So the tutorial's demo has a bug ?

Comment: You are right, it is bug in concrete producer `class Producer[T]`.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave, T is a String, but it doesn't have to be. It could be anything.

You pass a String to b.tell() no matter what, but b.tell()'s argument type is not guaranteed to be a String.